# Include a select statement after the output clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

Include a select statement after the output statementSet the CostYTD to $1000.00 for territories 1-4 on the Sales Territory table.  Provide an output statement that shows the territory id, new cost YTD and old cost YTD displayed as follows

```
TerritoryID     New Cost YTD     Old Cost YTD
------------    ------------     ------------

1               1000.00          0.00
```

This is the code  I have:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
UPDATE sales.SalesTerritory
SET CostYTD = 1000.00 
OUTPUT inserted.TerritoryID, deleted.CostYTD, inserted.CostYTD
WHERE TerritoryID=1 and TerritoryID=2 and TerritoryID=3 and TerritoryID=4
```

However when I add the select statement it tells me the column names aren't valid. I'm not sure what to do. Also I know that CostYTD needs to also be know as New cost YTD and old so do I do this? inserted.CostYTD = New Cost YTD?

Comment: `OUTPUT` isn't valid in MySQL - it's a T-SQL construct.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `OUTPUT` clause

Comment: Please show us the SELECT statement that fails.

Comment: The select statement i had was SELECT COSTYTD= 'New Cost YTD', TerritoryID

Answer (score 0):

I hope i get your problem right: you want to get info from the OUTPUT clause like 'deleted.field' or 'inserted.field' for each processed row to use it further on. Well, here's a try (nothing tested): the OUTPUT must be put into a table which you must create first befor the statement like so

```
DECLARE @outputtab TABLE(inserted_TerritoryID bigint,deleted_CostYTD money,inserted_CostYTD money)
```

(make sure the datatypes match). Within the statement you can then fill that table variable like so

```
OUTPUT inserted.TerritoryID,deleted.CostYTD,inserted.CostYTD INTO @outputtab
```

(order of fields in OUTPUT must match that of @outputtab). After that you can query that table variable. You could also build a temptable or a normal table.

Comment: I understand what you are saying however I am getting this error and I tried to look it up but am not finding an answer do you know what this means?
The target table 'Sales.SalesTerritory' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot have any enabled check constraints or any enabled rules. Found check constraint or rule 'CK_SalesTerritory_SalesYTD'.